# ubuntu 12.04 admin password account disabled

Tags: 12.04, password

i have ubuntu lts 12.04
i wanted to make a new administrator.....i created a new user..made it admin and made the earlier user standard....but accidentally the new admin user password says "account disabled"...  now  i can only log in with earlier user(standard) and not with admin......
i tried recovery mode
in the recovery mode it asks for "root password for maintenance"...which i don't know....
also if i try to solve using terminal in earlier user it says "user not in sudoers file.This incident will be reported"...........
how can i access the admin account or create a new one......help

Answer (score 0):

1) Boot from CD/DVD, chroot into your system and add user to admin group (`sudo adduser USERNAME admin`) or to `/etc/sudoers` (`sudo visudo`)

2) to enable accout use `passwd -u username`

For step by step howto read: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Comment: Before `chroot`, you have to `mount -o rw,remount /`

Comment: I just gave a general answer, all the steps are described in the article I linked.